# variable scope conflict Js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying to make a simple animation web application using `paperjs`, I have been reading the docs for it but I can't really grasp how this code works.

If you can provide me with headlines to search for or exactly what are the `js` parts that I am missing.

```
// To make sure the script isn't executed unless DOM is ready
window.onload = function(){
    // Whenever the user clicks on a keyboard button, this event handler is executed
    $('body').on('keypress', function(event) {

        var path = new paper.Path.Circle({
            center: [400, 200],
            radius: 10,                     
            fillColor: '#1abc9c'
        });

        console.log(path.fillColor);       // prints undefined
        console.log(path.fillColor.hue);   // prints undefined

        paper.view.onFrame = function(event) {
            // On each frame, increment:
            path.fillColor.hue += 1;       // works fine !!
            path.radius -= 1;              // doesn't work !!
        }
        // starts drawing
        paper.view.draw();
    }
}
```

First question: How is `path.fillColor.hue` is undefined in the first `console.log()` line but the first line inside `paper.view.onframe()` works fine ?

Second question: By the same concept as `path.fillColor.hue` I am trying to make another animation that shrinks the radius of my circles so I am decrementing `path.radius` in my animation function, however, this doen't work -though no error is raised.

Notes: 
1- `hue` is a property that changes the color of my circle, I got it from the docs.

2- I tried to put `paper.view.draw()` inside my `paper.view.onframe()` function as a solution as if it will draw a new circle with the new radius every time the `paper.view.onframe()` is called but this doesn't work.

3- I know that my code contains lots of repeating `paper.` and the `paperjs` docs purposes 2 conventions to avoid this but I am just trying to keep my mind on the most important things first before improving my code quality.

4- This isn't the complete code and I know that using `Jquery` isn't really useful as I could have replaced its use with `addEventListener()` but `keypress` event seems to have a problem so I decided to get back to it when I finish the code and eliminate `jquery` from my project.

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine" and "doesn't work" on the increment and decrement operations? One causes an error in the console and one doesn't?

Side note: I wouldn't worry about using or not using jQuery while you are still figuring out how paper works. Whatever is easiest for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the path is no longer a "circle" once you have created it. It's just a path. You need to interact with it in a slightly more complicated way to change the radius.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="paper-full.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                $('body').on('keypress', function(event) {
                    paper.setup('myCanvas');

                    var path = new paper.Path.Circle({
                        center: [400, 200],
                        radius: 10,
                        fillColor: '#1abc9c'
                    });

                    paper.view.onFrame = function(event) {
                        var currentRadius = path.bounds.width / 2,
                            newRadius = currentRadius - 1;
                        path.fillColor.hue += 1;
                        path.scale(newRadius / currentRadius);
                    }

                    paper.view.draw();
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I got the necessary info from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/xJTDWTQIFwQ which also discusses a slight problem with doing it this way that doesn't apply to your use case as presented.

Comment: Tell a lie, the radius starts `undefined` and becomes `NaN` after decrement. But the `console.log`s both print sensible output for me and I do get a color-changing circle.

Comment: The animation works, but the radius doesn't change.
My full version contains     paper.setup('myCanvas')    and I don't think I need paper.install(window)  as I am already calling methods from the paperjs library using the complete syntax paper.view() and paper.Path() not just view() and Path()

Comment: Yeah I definitely didn't understand the problem you were having. But now I do and I updated with what I think is a solution :D Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot for the information source note!